# How do we set 'INFLUXDB_DATA_DIR ' environment variable?

Tags: windows, influxdb

How do we set `INFLUXDB_DATA_DIR` environment variable for `influxDB`? as there is no such field in my `influxdb.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set like any other `environment variable` in System variables where :

Variable Name: `INFLUXDB_DATA_DIR`
Variable Value: `Path\\where\\you\\want\\to\\store\\data`